# Selecting and deselecting markers in leaflet under R shiny?

Tags: r, leaflet-r, shiny

I would like to write a script that selects a marker on the map whenever I click on it and then deselect it when I click/select another marker (that is, so that no more that one marker is selected on the map at any time). I managed to get the selection bit working for the multiple "current" marker, but not the deselection of the last clicked marker, partly because I am confused with the time ordering/reactivity of objects in shiny environment. I attempted to use leafletProxy() to substitute default icons with selected icons to mimic selection, but that only took me this far.

[image: Clinics map]

```
library(shiny) 
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(leafletOutput("clinics.map"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
     icons <- makeIcon(iconUrl = "clinic_icon.png", iconWidth = 27, iconHeight = 30)
     icons.sel <- makeIcon(iconUrl = "clinic_icon_selected.png", iconWidth = 27, iconHeight = 30)

   output$clinics.map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(data = clinics) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
      setView(lat = 37.900000, lng = -121.900000, zoom = 9) %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, icon = icons, layerId = ~ID) 
   }) 

   previous.markers <- reactiveValues(markerID = c(), marker.lat = c(), marker.lon = c())

   observeEvent(input$clinics.map_marker_click, {
      marker.click <- input$clinics.map_marker_click
      previous.markers$markerID <- c(previous.markers$markerID, marker.click$id)
      previous.markers$marker.lat <- c(previous.markers$marker.lat, marker.click$lat)
      previous.markers$marker.lon <- c(previous.markers$marker.lon, marker.click$lng)

      last.marker.id <- tail(previous.markers$markerID, 1)
      last.marker.lat <- tail(previous.markers$lat, 1)
      last.marker.lon <- tail(previous.markers$lon, 1)

      leafletProxy("clinics.map", session) %>%
      removeMarker(last.marker.id) %>% 
      #addMarkers(last.marker.id,      # This bit doesn't work b/c there's no last marker initially
      #           lng = last.marker.lon,
      #           lat = last.marker.lat,
      #           icon = icons) %>% 
      addMarkers(marker.click$id,
                 lng = marker.click$lng,
                 lat = marker.click$lat,
                 icon = icons.sel)
   })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @Telarian Unfortunately, no. For an unknown reason, it appears that `marker.click` would store the marker IDs incorrectly. On the first click, it stores the ID of the first marker, whereas on the second click it would store both the first and second marker IDs together. On the third and further clicks it stores the correct ID of the marker clicked. This quirkiness makes it difficult to create the definition of what is the "previous" marker. I therefore decided not to proceed with this interactive feature for my app, but I would still be curious to know if anyone finds a solution.